# how to define Ext.elevateFunction

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

"I can't find Ext.elevateFunction defined anywhere in the ExtJS documentation, yet it's being used in the codebase. I'm curious to know how it's defined."

**Here is the usage of Ext.elevateFunction function in the code base:**

/**
* This is the target of the user-supplied `Ext.elevateFunction`. It wraps the
* call to a function and concludes by calling {@link Ext#fireIdle}.
* @since 6.5.1
* @private
*/

```
    doElevate: function() {
        var fn = elevateFn,
            args = elevateArgs,
            scope = elevateScope;

        // We really should never re-enter here, but we'll latch these vars just
        // in case.
        elevateFn = elevateArgs = elevateScope = null;
        elevateRet = args ? fn.apply(scope, args) : fn.call(scope);

        // Be sure to fire the idle event while elevated or its handlers will
        // be running in an unprivileged context.
        Ext.fireIdle();
    },

    /**
     * Runs the given `fn` directly or using the user-provided `Ext.elevateFunction`
     * (if present). After calling the `fn` the global `idle` event is fired using
     * the {@link Ext#fireIdle} method.
     *
     * @param {Function} fn 
     * @param {Object} [scope] 
     * @param {Array} [args] 
     * @param {Object} [timer] 
     * @return {Mixed} 
     * @since 6.5.1
     * @private
     */
    elevate: function(fn, scope, args
                      //<debug>
                      , timer // eslint-disable-line comma-style
                      //</debug>
    ) {
        var ret;

        if (args && !args.length) {
            args = null;
        }

        Ext._suppressIdle = false;

        //<debug>
        if (timer) {
            timer.tick();
        }
        //</debug>

        if (Ext.elevateFunction) {
            elevateFn = fn;
            elevateScope = scope;
            elevateArgs = args;

            // We reuse the same fn here to avoid GC pressure.
            Ext.elevateFunction(Ext.doElevate);

            ret = elevateRet;

            elevateRet = null;
        }
        else {
            ret = args ? fn.apply(scope, args) : fn.call(scope);

            Ext.fireIdle();
        }

        //<debug>
        if (timer) {
            timer.tock();
        }
        //</debug>

        return ret;
    },
```

I checked on EXT namespace, the elevateFunction is undefined.